# Api monitoring .net

Tags: rest

I am novice in Web API. Apologize if any question is not making sense.

I have several Web APIs developed in `.NET` and hosted on the same sever. These APIs are consumed by different applications. Here I wanted to monitor APIs. Monitoring includes:

1. How many applications are consuming my API?
2. How many hit counts to the API by different applications?
3. Is there any why we can restrict an application to access the application(ex. An application is given only 5 hits to the api per day)?

And also it would be helpful, if there are any tools available to do the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant to solve specific problems and not a broad range of questions like you have posted. Such questions are off topic on SO. I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Treblle .Net SDK.

Treblle lets you monitor and observe your API and all the features you listed are packed in Treblle.

https://github.com/treblle/treblle-net